# Correlation of means

Tags: correlation, measurement-error

Can I (and how) calculate the correlation between two sets of data where each point in both data sets is a mean +/- SD (multiple measurements have been conducted for each point). Clearly, I can correlate the means, but is there a test that also takes into account SD.

Comment: Do you know the n in each mean?  Do you know the distribution (Normal or uniform or whatever)?

Comment: I have n and the distribution is normal. I am doing some correlation analysis between two parameters for a group of patients. Next I used cluster analysis to divide patients into groups according to one parameter, and now I want to see the correlation of means of these two parameters